# Does AMP Google support recaptcha?

Tags: amp-html, recaptcha

I am trying to resolve a spam problem in AMP Google. I thought the best way to do this would be to add a captcha.

Does AMP Google support reCAPTCHA?

Answer (score 1):

Author of `amp-recaptcha-input` here.

Sorry for replying to a super old question, but just wanted to say reCAPTCHA v3 for AMP is now launched, and publicly available for AMP pages as we released this last week for AMP Conf. It is now no longer experimental, and is good to go! Here is some documentation on how to get started: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-recaptcha-input/

Comment: This says that it supports v3, what about v2?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee It only supports reCAPTCHA v3. I went ahead and updated my answer, thank you for pointing that out! :)

Comment: @Torch2424 Does this component work with server-side rendering?

Comment: @connected_user Yes, it should! If by server side rendering, you mean you are server side rendering amp components to a static page using something like Mustache or Next.js AMP implementation, than I wouldn't see why not :)

Comment: @connected_user Just wanted to follow up, someone else opened an issue asking about server side rendering: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/22279

As of today though, nothing conclusive has been found. But feel free to chime in with your issue (if you have one) as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, for now, there is no support for image-based ReCaptcha. But the Google AMP Project Team is already working on it. You can post your queries on GitHub  here https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/2273

I found this answer on below site, and after researching while, I think they are right.

[Is Recaptcha supported by AMP HTML?](https://web.archive.org/web/20170918202956/http://www.knowamp.com/question/Vmtaa2QySnNRbEpRVkRBOQ==/Is-Recaptcha-supported-by-AMP-HTML)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, yes this issue has been taken care of and is in fact developer-error not an error in the amp component library :)